# Which exceptions do you catch when you don't specify an exception class in ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

Which exceptions are you catching when you don't specify an exception class like this:

```
begin
  # do something
rescue
  puts "Exception!"
end
```

Answer (score 7):

According to my copy of *Programming Ruby 1.9*,

> A rescue clause with no parameter is treated as if it had a parameter of `StandardError`.

And here's the documentation from [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000030):

> By default, `rescue`  only intercepts `StandardError` and  its descendants, but you can specify which exceptions you want handled, as arguments. (This technique does not  work when  `rescue`  is in  statement-modifier position.)

The Why Not Wiki [has the Exception hierarchy available](http://whynotwiki.com/Ruby_/_Exception_handling#Exception_hierarchy) if you need to reference it.

As a quick reference, the Exception classes that are not derived from `StandardError` are:

- `fatal`
- `NoMemoryError`
- `ScriptError`
- `SignalException`
- `SystemExit`
- `SystemStackError`

Comment: Note that there are [several more standard exceptions inheriting from the above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118745/is-systemexit-a-special-kind-of-exception/5120214#5120214) that are, therefor, also not covered. Most commonly: `LoadError`, `NotImplementedError`, `SyntaxError`.