# Is SystemExit a special kind of Exception?

Tags: ruby, exception, exit

How does `SystemExit` behave differently from other `Exception`s?  I think I understand some of the reasoning about why it *wouldn't* be good to raise a proper Exception.  For example, you wouldn't want something strange like this to happen:

```
begin
  exit
rescue => e
  # Silently swallow up the exception and don't exit
end
```

But **how** does the `rescue` ignore `SystemExit`?  (What criteria does it use?)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm It certainly is a FAQ from mailing list and IRC, but I can't seem to find this question exactly on S/O. The closest I found was _["Which exceptions do you catch when you don't specify an exception class in Ruby"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748515/which-exceptions-do-you-catch-when-you-dont-specify-an-exception-class-in-ruby)_, but it's sort of a duplicate answer, not a duplicate question.

Comment: @Andrew I thought someone else had to have asked the same thing too, but I didn't find anything that specifically answered how `SystemExit` is handled.  @Phrogz Thanks for the link to the related Q.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you write `rescue` without one or more classes, [it is the same](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/frameset.html?content=http%3A//phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html%23handlingexceptions) as writing:

```
begin
  ...
rescue StandardError => e
  ...
end
```

There are Exceptions that do not inherit from `StandardError`, however. `SystemExit` is one of these, and so it is not captured. Here is a subset of the hierarchy in Ruby 1.9.2, which you can [find out yourself](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/09/06/rubys-exception-hierarchy):

```
BasicObject
  Exception
    NoMemoryError
    ScriptError
      LoadError
        Gem::LoadError
      NotImplementedError
      SyntaxError
    SecurityError
    SignalException
      Interrupt
    StandardError
      ArgumentError
      EncodingError
        Encoding::CompatibilityError
        Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError
        Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError
        Encoding::UndefinedConversionError
      FiberError
      IOError
        EOFError
      IndexError
        KeyError
        StopIteration
      LocalJumpError
      NameError
        NoMethodError
      RangeError
        FloatDomainError
      RegexpError
      RuntimeError
      SystemCallError
      ThreadError
      TypeError
      ZeroDivisionError
    SystemExit
    SystemStackError
    fatal
```

You can thus capture *just* `SystemExit` with:

```
begin
  ...
rescue SystemExit => e
  ...
end
```

...or you can choose to capture *every* exception, including `SystemExit` with:

```
begin
  ...
rescue Exception => e
  ...
end
```

Try it yourself:

```
begin
  exit 42
  puts "No no no!"
rescue Exception => e
  puts "Nice try, buddy."
end
puts "And on we run..."

#=> "Nice try, buddy."
#=> "And on we run..."
```

---

Note that this example will not work in (some versions of?) IRB, which supplies its own exit method that masks the normal Object#exit.

In 1.8.7:

```
method :exit
#=> #<Method: Object(IRB::ExtendCommandBundle)#exit>
```

In 1.9.3:

```
method :exit
#=> #<Method: main.irb_exit>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I knew you could capture `SystemExit` by itself, but I didn't know that not specifying an exception class causes only `StandardError` exceptions to be rescued.  Seems to explain it -- thanks!

Comment: This is awesome for testing whether or not something exits

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
begin
  exit
  puts "never get here"
rescue SystemExit
  puts "rescued a SystemExit exception"
end

puts "after begin block"
```

The exit `status` / `success?`, etc. can be read too:

```
begin
  exit 1
rescue SystemExit => e
  puts "Success? #{e.success?}" # Success? false
end

begin
  exit
rescue SystemExit => e
  puts "Success? #{e.success?}" # Success? true
end
```

Full list of methods: `[:status, :success?, :exception, :message, :backtrace, :backtrace_locations, :set_backtrace, :cause]`